# I cant make div float on the right side

Tags: html, css

I need the pockeat item place right beside the sidebar, and I tried many of the solutions I found on the Internet, but none of them work.

This is my code:

```css
.header {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    top:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    color:#1c1919;
    font-family:century gothic;
    font-size:56px;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:center;
    text-align:center;
    top:2%;
}

.navbar {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:8%;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:4px solid #1c1919;
    border-bottom:4px solid #1c1919;
    padding:5px; 
}

.navbar a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1c1919;
    font-family:century gothic;
    font-size:32px;
    padding:0 30px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:century gothic;
    height:82%;
    width:20%;
    border-right:2px solid #1c1919;
}    

button.accordion {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #1c1919;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #1c1919;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;

}

.panel li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:century gothic;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    color: #1c1919;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}

.content-body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:82%;
    width:80%;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
}

.content {
    height:60px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:century gothic;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!navbar>
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#Newest">HOME</a>
    <a href="#Newest">NEWEST</a>
    <a href="#Recommended">RECOMMENDED</a>
    <a href="#ATF">ALL TIME FAVE</a>
    <a href="#Newest">CONTACT US</a>
</div>

<!sidebar>  
<div class="sidebar">
    <button class="accordion">Gadgets</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Furniture</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Wheelchair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lights</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Table/ Chair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Lifestyle</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Window Blinds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mask</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gardening</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Instruments</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tuner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Kitchen/Bathroom</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ready-to-Eat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Pet</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Stationery</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pen Pouch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Toy</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Doll</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Card</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Other</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pill Case</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<!content>
<div class="content-body">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="/image/bento/20170521223952w6A7Gz9kL8KlUW1g.jpg-w600.jpg" style="height:80%; width:100%">
        <br>Pockeat
    </div>
</div>
```

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your border of 2% eats into your sidebar width making it a total of 22%, so your sidebar needs to be 18% with a 2% border, please see the updated CSS.

I have also removed all of your height attributes and they are not needed. The content within the divs will adapt naturally. Another amendment I made is making the font you are using global by adding it into the "body" selector within your CSS.

```
body {
  font-family:century gothic;
}
.header {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    color:#1c1919;
    font-size:56px;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:center;
    text-align:center;
    top:2%;
}

.navbar {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:4px solid #1c1919;
    border-bottom:4px solid #1c1919;
    padding:5px; 
}

.navbar a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1c1919;
    font-size:32px;
    padding:0 30px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:18%;
    border-right:2px solid #1c1919;
    float:left;
}    

button.accordion {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #1c1919;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #1c1919;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    color: #1c1919;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}

.content-body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:80%;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
}
.content {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No `float` was added to `.sidebar`
2. total `width` of both (i.e. `.sidebar` and `.content-body`) should be less than `100%` as you added a `border` to the right side of `.sidebar` as below,

```css
        background-color:#ffffff;
        top:0;
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        color:#1c1919;
        font-family:century gothic;
        font-size:56px;
        padding:15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        float:center;
        text-align:center;
        top:2%;
    }

    .navbar {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        height:8%;
        width: 100%;
        border-top:4px solid #1c1919;
        border-bottom:4px solid #1c1919;
        padding:5px; 
    }

    .navbar a {
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#1c1919;
        font-family:century gothic;
        font-size:32px;
        padding:0 30px;
    }

    .sidebar {
        background:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:century gothic;
        height:82%;
        width:20%;
        border-right:2px solid #1c1919;
      float:left;
      overflow:hidden;
    }    

    button.accordion {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        color: #1c1919;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        opacity:0.7;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: #1c1919;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    
    }

    .panel li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:century gothic;
        font-size:15px;
        text-align:left;
        color: #1c1919;
        padding:10px;
        display:block;
    }

    .content-body {
        background-color:#ffffff;
        height:82%;
        width:calc(80% - 5%);
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px;
        float:right;
    }

    .content {
        height:60px;
        width:50px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:century gothic;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:20px;
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#Newest">HOME</a>
    <a href="#Newest">NEWEST</a>
    <a href="#Recommended">RECOMMENDED</a>
    <a href="#ATF">ALL TIME FAVE</a>
    <a href="#Newest">CONTACT US</a>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <button class="accordion">Gadgets</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Furniture</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Wheelchair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lights</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Table/ Chair</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Lifestyle</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Window Blinds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mask</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gardening</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Instruments</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tuner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Kitchen/Bathroom</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ready-to-Eat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Pet</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Stationery</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pen Pouch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Toy</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Doll</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Card</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="accordion">Other</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pill Case</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="content-body">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="/image/bento/20170521223952w6A7Gz9kL8KlUW1g.jpg-w600.jpg" style="height:80%; width:100%">
        <br>Pockeat
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left` to your `sidebar div` & add `box-sizing` to globally. 
Check updated snippet below:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #1c1919;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 56px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    top: 2%;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 4px solid #1c1919;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1c1919;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navbar a {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1c1919;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: century gothic;
    height: 82%;
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 2px solid #1c1919;
    float: left;
}

button.accordion {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #1c1919;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #1c1919;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: century gothic;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #1c1919;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.content-body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 82%;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.content {
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: century gothic;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#Newest">HOME</a>
    <a href="#Newest">NEWEST</a>
    <a href="#Recommended">RECOMMENDED</a>
    <a href="#ATF">ALL TIME FAVE</a>
    <a href="#Newest">CONTACT US</a>
</div>


<div class="sidebar">
    <button class="accordion">Gadgets</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Furniture</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Wheelchair</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lights</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Table/ Chair</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Lifestyle</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Window Blinds</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mask</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gardening</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Instruments</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tuner</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Kitchen/Bathroom</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ready-to-Eat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pot</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Pet</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Stationery</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Pen Pouch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Toy</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Doll</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Card</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Other</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Pill Case</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content-body">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="/image/bento/20170521223952w6A7Gz9kL8KlUW1g.jpg-w600.jpg" style="height:80%; width:100%">
        <br>Pockeat
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your sidebar and your content-body are too large to be floated.

If you want to use width: 80% with a padding, you should use:`width: calc(80% - padding)`, same for borders.

```css
    .header {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     top:0;
     height:10%;
     width:100%;
     color:#1c1919;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:56px;
     padding:15px;
     text-decoration:none;
     float:center;
     text-align:center;
     top:2%;
    }

    .navbar {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     height:8%;
     width: 100%;
     border-top:4px solid #1c1919;
     border-bottom:4px solid #1c1919;
     padding:5px; 
    }

    .navbar a {
     text-align:center;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#1c1919;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:32px;
     padding:0 30px;
    }

    .sidebar {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     height:82%;
     width:20%;
        float: left;
    }    

    button.accordion {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
     color: #1c1919;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 18px;
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     text-align: left;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
     opacity:0.7;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
     content: '\002B';
     color: #1c1919;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
     content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
     padding: 0 18px;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
 
    }

    .panel li a {
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:15px;
     text-align:left;
     color: #1c1919;
     padding:10px;
     display:block;
    }

    .content-body {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     height:82%;
     width:80%;
     text-decoration:none;
     float:left;
    }

    .content {
     height:60px;
     width:50px;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     padding:10px;
     font-size:20px;
     display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <!navbar>
    <div class="navbar">
     <a href="#Newest">HOME</a>
     <a href="#Newest">NEWEST</a>
     <a href="#Recommended">RECOMMENDED</a>
     <a href="#ATF">ALL TIME FAVE</a>
     <a href="#Newest">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>

    <!sidebar> 
    <div class="sidebar">
     <button class="accordion">Gadgets</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Furniture</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wheelchair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Table/ Chair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Lifestyle</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Window Blinds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mask</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gardening</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Instruments</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tuner</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Kitchen/Bathroom</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ready-to-Eat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kit</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Pet</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Stationery</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Pen Pouch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Toy</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doll</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Card</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Other</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Pill Case</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!content>
    <div class="content-body">
     <div class="content">
      <img src="/image/bento/20170521223952w6A7Gz9kL8KlUW1g.jpg-w600.jpg" style="height:80%; width:100%">
      <br>Pockeat
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it will solve your issue.

```css
.header {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     top:0;
     height:10%;
     width:100%;
     color:#1c1919;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:56px;
     padding:15px;
     text-decoration:none;
     float:center;
     text-align:center;
     top:2%;
    }

    .navbar {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     text-align:center;
     overflow:hidden;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     height:8%;
     width: 100%;
     border-top:4px solid #1c1919;
     border-bottom:4px solid #1c1919;
     padding:5px; 
    }

    .navbar a {
     text-align:center;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#1c1919;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:32px;
     padding:0 30px;
    }

    .sidebar {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     height:82%;
     width:20%;
     border-right:2px solid #1c1919;
      float: left;
    }    

    button.accordion {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
     color: #1c1919;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 18px;
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     text-align: left;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
     opacity:0.7;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
     content: '\002B';
     color: #1c1919;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
     content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
     padding: 0 18px;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
 
    }

    .panel li a {
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     font-size:15px;
     text-align:left;
     color: #1c1919;
     padding:10px;
     display:block;
    }

    .content-body {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     height:82%;
     width:calc(100% - 20% - 22px);
     text-decoration:none;
     padding:10px;
     float:right;
    }

    .content {
     height:60px;
     width:50px;
     background-color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-family:century gothic;
     padding:10px;
     font-size:20px;
     display:block;
    }
```

```html
<!--navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
     <a href="#Newest">HOME</a>
     <a href="#Newest">NEWEST</a>
     <a href="#Recommended">RECOMMENDED</a>
     <a href="#ATF">ALL TIME FAVE</a>
     <a href="#Newest">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>
  
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!--sidebar --> 
    <div class="sidebar">
     <button class="accordion">Gadgets</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Furniture</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wheelchair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Table/ Chair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Lifestyle</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Window Blinds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mask</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gardening</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Instruments</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flute</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tuner</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Kitchen/Bathroom</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ready-to-Eat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kit</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Pet</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Stationery</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Pen Pouch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Toy</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doll</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Card</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     <button class="accordion">Other</button>
      <div class="panel">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Pill Case</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fitness</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bicycle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wine</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content-->
    <div class="content-body">
     <div class="content">
      <img src="/image/bento/20170521223952w6A7Gz9kL8KlUW1g.jpg-w600.jpg" style="height:80%; width:100%">
      <br>Pockeat
     </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```